# Excel - compare two documents?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, hyperlink

I'm trying to link two Excel books together. They are an exact copy of each other, but if you edit either one, the other should get updated too. I know you can do this using the link function, but that's unidirectional. I would need to know how you can do this in both directions.

```
Book1.xls
   Sheet1
      A1: Hello!
      A2: Goodbye!

Book2.xls
   Sheet1
      A1: Hello!
      A2: Goodbye!
```

Now if I have a link between Book2 and Book1, anything edited in Book1 will be changed in Book2, but not vice versa!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One question - if the files are meant to be exact copies why have 2 copies?

A possible example is to use a Workbook_SheetChange event so that any changes to a workbook update the other workbook. However, this really only works when you change values and not formats etc.

Eg 2 workbooks Book1.xlsm & Book2.xlsm, in Book1.xlsm in THISWORKBOOK object enter

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim MyObj As Object, strCopyto As String

 strCopyto = "C:\Users\osknows\Desktop\Book2.xlsm"

 Set MyObj = GetObject(strCopyto)
 MyObj.Parent.Windows(MyObj.Name).Visible = True
 Target.Copy Destination:=MyObj.Sheets(Sh.Name).Range(Target.Address)
 MyObj.Close savechanges:=True

end sub
```

do the same in Book2.xlsm but change `strCopyto = "C:\Users\osknows\Desktop\Book1.xlsm"`

this is one of many ways it could be done